# Django atomic check and decrement

Tags: database, django, concurrency, locking

I have a model variable, let's call it .actions which is an integer. The idea is that people can only do stuff if there are actions left.

How do I do a check if actions are > 0 and subsequently decrement the actions atomically? I don't want them to ever hit negative.

```
if model.actions > 0:
  Model.objects.filter().update(actions=F('actions')-1)
```

I don't think transactions solve this because they don't deal with locking. The [select_for_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) seems to solve this, but that documentation is also frightfully unclear. Will it work with the default transaction setup or does it need additional settings?

Comment: I can put this in front: teamQS = Team.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=team.id) but then I get the team from the queryset as teamQS[0] and check that and write to that team. At which point will select_for_update yield the lock?

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution:

```
returnValue = MyObject.objects.filter(pk=x, points__gt=0).update(points=F('points')-1)
```

Which only updates when the condition is met and gives you a return value which you can check if it happened (which means if the points were indeed larger than 0).